# Does typing @username on my phone in comments ping people?

Tags: support, comment, comment-replies, mobile-web

On my laptop, when I type @us, there is a little box with "username" and when I click on that, after I submit my comment it pings the person. However on my phone this doesn't happen. If I type out @username, does it still ping them? It seems like it doesn't.

Comment: Related posts on the main meta: [Add the comments \@ auto-complete to mobile theme](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/197719), [Add \@reply autocomplete when commenting on the Android app](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/197985), [Comment autocomplete \@reply in iOS app](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230852).

Comment: This is a comment so that there are two commentators so that you can test at-pinging here if you want.

Comment: @quid I'm using the mobile app right now. Did you get a notification?

Comment: @IvoTerek yes, I got notified.

Comment: @Zachary Selk: Maybe you could specify whether you are using android app or ios app or simply mobile web. (I have added the tag [mobile web](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/mobile-web/info), if that's not correct, please replace it by the correct tag.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a typed-in at-notification will ping. You could *also* type it out on your laptop. I frequently do this. (Why do you think it does not?)

The feature you describe is *only* there to ease the input of a notifying string. For the notification it is ultimately irrelevant how the string came into the input box (auto-complete, typed-in, copy-paste, it does not change a thing); the submitted comment is parsed and processed.

Note that there is no need to type out the full string. The first three letters or any longer *starting* sub-string (with spaces removed) will do. Note the 'starting' though and note that the string must be an actual substring and not just match the start, so:  @Zach will do, yet @Selk won't and @Zack won't either.

[To be complete, let me add that slightly more could be said about the string matching, but for the most part what is between @ and the first subsequent space (or character that cannot be contained in a user name) must be an exact starting substring, only adding a *single* punctuation is still fine and some special characters are identified.]

Comment: @quip: What if the first three letters agree, but then they disagree and there is no "better ping target"?

Comment: Will not ping. Of course I got a ping here, but so will you @Btbg.

Comment: @qunb, thanks...

Comment: I understood quip and  I rotated by 1 to get Btbg but qunb beats me?

Comment: Reflection on two axes.